# Create a C++ container that contain the filenames within a directory

Tags: c++, directory, containers, filenames

I need to generate a container of filenames within a directory in C++ and it must be cross platform compatible. Someone recommended using the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` data structure. Is this the best option and if so how would I implement it?

The user will not enter the filenames, but rather the C++ function will automatically search the directory and create a container of filenames. I don't know how to read in filenames like this either.

I have a strong focus on standards too, so `<dirent.h>` is not an ideal solution because it is not ISO C standard even though its a header in the C POSIX library.

Comment: Neither the C nor C++ standard have anything about directories.  You will have to use some other standard, like POSIX, to deal with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing WIN32_FIND_DATA isn't your best bet for cross platform, but there are probably libraries to help provide it on linux.

Consider using [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to dump the files into a [`std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html).

Something like this (adapted from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread74944.html)):

```
void show_files(const path & directory)
{
  if(!exists(directory)) return;

  directory_iterator end ;
  for( directory_iterator iter(directory) ; iter != end ; ++iter )
    if (is_directory(*iter)) continue;  // skip directories
    cout << "File: " << iter->native_file_string() << "\n" ;
  }
}
```

Comment: `boost::filesystem` is strongly recommended: it’s been accepted by the C++ standards committee as part of TR2 so it will eventually be built-in to most compilers (under `std::tr2::sys`).

Answer (score 0):

Um, I don't think anything with Win32 is cross platform. If you just need to store directory names, can't you just use an array, or a vector?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). Untested:

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace bf = boost::filesystem;
typedef std::vector<bf::path> path_container;

path_container enumerate_files(const bf::path& pDirectory)
{
    path_container result;

    if (!bf::exists(pDirectory))
        return result;

    bf::directory_iterator iter(pDirectory);
    bf::directory_iterator last;

    for (; iter != last; ++iter)
        if (bf::is_regular_file(iter->status()))
            result.push_back(iter->path());

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    path_container c = enumerate_files("./");

    std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<bf::path>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```